# Webpack - Using Script Loader in webpack.config.json

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am just starting to dip my toes into the world of webpack.  I am using the awesome Vue.js with vueify, so therefore my modules are ES6.

One difficulty I am having is loading some 3rd party jQuery plugins.  I am using the ProvidePlugin to load jQuery - which works fine.

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
```

I then have a directory called plugins containing misc jQuery plugins.  My understanding is the script loader just loads these into the bundled file as strings, and they are eval-ed when the bundle loads.  These scripts can then be used as if they were loaded in a regular script tag (i.e., no import needed).

But I just cant get any of the plugins to work.  Below is my loaders array.  What I am doing wrong (or not doing)?

```
loaders: [

        // process *.vue files using vue-loader
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue'
        },
        // process *.js files using babel-loader
        // the exclude pattern is important so that we don't
        // apply babel transform to all the dependencies!
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /plugins\.js$/,
            loader: 'script-loader' #tried script too
        }

    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I can sympathize with the difficulty of getting jQuery plugins to work with webpack. While I don't have a solution to this specific configuration, I have found it useful to use a cdn to keep development rolling along until further troubleshooting can be done. Below is an example.

In your .html template file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In index.js or whatever your main entry point is:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

In your webpack config:

```
externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

Since this approach involves direct use of script tags it may work more reliably, while temporarily sacrificing opportunities for optimization and bundling.

Answer (score 0):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'React': path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react/react"),
  'ReactDOM': path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom"),
  "jQuery": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery"),
  "$": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery")
})
```

resolve you lib path

Comment: Firstly why did this get downvoted? Secondly, would this look into node_modules and then add the scripts to your bundle.js on compile?